# google mobAd is conflict with Parse framework in (-ObjC) how to solve this issue?

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, parse-platform

i have the google mobile Ad in my project and to make it work you should add -ObjC to other linker flag
but i have added Parse framework to my project ,and this one need to remove -ObjC so it can compile 
after i run the project it crashes on this exception :

```
Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[GADObjectPrivate changeState:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x1dde57b0'
```

so please anyone can help with this conflict ??
or i should use another Ad engine if there is no solution ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `-ObjC` with Parse. When you use that flag, though, you will need to include the Facebook SDK and its dependencies as well. That's because the `-ObjC` flag tells the linker to load *all frameworks and classes* referenced by your code, which turns the optional Facebook SDK library into a required library.

Instead of using `-ObjC`, [consider using `-force_load` to cherry pick the frameworks to be loaded](https://www.parse.com/questions/using-the-parse-ios-sdk-without-including-the-facebook-sdk).